# Angular-translate filter inside ng-style

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

is it possible to use the angular-translate (pascaltrend) plugin within an ng-style in AngularJS:

I have:

```
<div class="inspiration-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(//' + S3_BUCKET + '.' + PHOTO_SERVER_URL + '/img/departures/' + departurePhoto + ')'}">
```

and I need something like:

```
<div class="inspiration-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(//' + S3_BUCKET + '.' + PHOTO_SERVER_URL + '/img/departures/' + departurePhoto | translate + ')'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
<div class="inspiration-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{'/' + S3_BUCKET + '.' + PHOTO_SERVER_URL + '/img/departures/'}}{{'departurePhoto' | translate }})'}"></div>
```

I'm asuming you have this as variable in scope
**S3_BUCKET** and **PHOTO_SERVER_URL**

Comment: I changed the approach. So I´m not going to test it anymore. Thanks anyway!